# How do I fix div and img alignment error inside table

Tags: html, css, email

I'm setting up a mkt email but when it's sent by email the code breaks and looks like the image below

[exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfBA5.jpg)

```html
            <tr>
                <td style="height:40px;background-color:#eceded">&nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td align="center" width="100%" style="background-color:#eceded">
                    <a style="text-decoration:none"
                        href="https://seslink.sescrio.org.br/cl/POlcL/C99-/720b/Nr-qDmFVJdW/BN3W/EFG52VBKt2N/1/"
                        target="_blank">
                        <img src="http://www.unifeso.edu.br/uploads/email-marketing/5fb9fd6d878c37f87e21a077b4dc6ad4.jpg"
                            alt="" style="width: 207px;border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;float: left;margin-left: 71px;">
                        <div
                            style="background-color: #aef2b9;width: 50%;color: #6a6a6a;border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;margin-left: 219px;height: 209px;">
                            <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1><br>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi in enim iusto numquam
                                architecto nisi voluptate saepe nam, aspernatur ullam corporis maxime nobis soluta sed
                                ducimus accusantium quam dolore eum!</p>
                            <img src="https://www.unifeso.edu.br/email-news/images/btn_news.png" alt=""
                                style="width: 190px; margin-top: -6px; margin-left: 7px;">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
                        <tr>
                <td style="height:40px;background-color:#eceded">&nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
```

I want the div to be aligned with the image

Comment: Can you post an image of what it's supposed to look like? It's not clear if the button is supposed to hang low, or if it's supposed to be between the headline and body text?

Answer (score 0):

The alignment offset is due to the default `margin-top` of the `h1` element which goes outside of its parent, creating that offset ("collapsing margins"). To avoid that, add `margin-top: 0` to `h1`. To still create some space above that `h1`, you can add a `padding-top` in addition:

```css
h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" width="100%" style="background-color:#eceded">
      <a style="text-decoration:none" href="https://seslink.sescrio.org.br/cl/POlcL/C99-/720b/Nr-qDmFVJdW/BN3W/EFG52VBKt2N/1/" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300" alt="" style="width: 207px;border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;float: left;margin-left: 71px;">
        <div style="background-color: #ffffff;width: 50%;color: #6a6a6a;border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;margin-left: 219px;height: 209px;">
          <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1><br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi in enim iusto numquam architecto nisi voluptate saepe nam, aspernatur ullam corporis maxime nobis soluta sed ducimus accusantium quam dolore eum!</p>
          <img src="https://#/email-news/images/btn_news.png" alt="" style="width: 190px; margin-top: -6px; margin-left: 7px;">
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

P.S.: For your own solution, you'll have to use a class on that `h1`and create the CSS rul for that class to be able to address it independently from other `h1` elements (or a combined selector that addresses `h1` only inside those particular elements which might already have a class you can use)